# Splitting a set of integers over a set of bins

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation, partitions

I have a problem that feels like it should be simple but I'm just drawing a blank on. I've got a set of integers, e.g.

```
ogSet = PadRight[IntegerPartitions[20][[400]], 15]

{6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

and a set of bins, e.g.,

```
bins = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11}, {12, 13, 14}, {15}};
```

and I want to find the number of *unique* ways I can split these integers over the bins.

That is, I basically want to calculate this

```
testPerms = Permutations[ogSet][[;; 100]];
Table[
  Map[Sort@p[[#]] &, bins],
  {p, testPerms}
  ] // DeleteDuplicates

{
 {{2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}},
 {{2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}},
 {{2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0}},
 {{2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1}},
 {{2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}},
 {{2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0}},
 {{2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1}},
 {{2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0}},
 {{2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1}},
 {{1, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 1, 2}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}},
 {{1, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}},
 {{1, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0}},
 {{1, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1}},
 {{1, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 0, 0}, {0}},
 {{1, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {0}},
 {{1, 3, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {2}}
 }
```

but obviously as this number of terms gets larger, it becomes unfeasible to generate and test *every* permutation.

I'm sure there's a way to do this by mapping the `ogSet` to a set of character classes like

```
ogClasses = Counts[ogSet]

<|6 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 0 -> 8|>
```

and then doing some kind of intersection of those character classes with the bins, but I'm blanking on how to do this efficiently

Comment: In your solution example, are these combinations complete, or there are more? For instance, can 6 go to the last (15th) bin?

Comment: All possible permutations are allowed. I just didn't want to put too many out there in the name of keeping the wall of text small.

Comment: Are equal-length bins considered distinct? For example, if I had two 1-element bins, would `{... {1}, {0}}` and `{... {0}, {1}}` be considered different configurations?

Comment: @thorimur yeah for my purposes each bin has an associated tag

Answer (score 2):

Here is *a* solution, but I'm sure someone smarter can do better. I'm gonna make use of the fact that it's easy to distribute *one* bag of balls over `N` bins, so we can reduce the original list to its set of unique classes and recursively refine.

For a single set of `numEls` balls split over our bins, we'll do things a little clumsily by taking all the permutations of the integer partitions, the saving grace of which is that the number of elements in the partition is restricted to the number of bins we have

```
getSplits[numEls_, binSizes_] :=
 Block[
  {
   parts = 
    PadRight[#, Length[binSizes]] & /@ 
     IntegerPartitions[numEls, Length[binSizes]],
   perms,
   binChanges,
   sel
   },
  Join[##] & @@@
   Transpose@
    Table[
     perms = Permutations[p];
     binChanges = ConstantArray[binSizes, Length[perms]] - perms;
     sel = Min[#] >= 0 & /@ binChanges;
     {
      Pick[perms, sel],
      Pick[binChanges, sel]
      },
     {p, parts}
     ]
  ]
```

You'll notice we're also tracking how the bins change once we take into account each partition/permutation, which will allow us to apply this recursively over each bag.

The trick here will be to build a tree that tracks *where* things were added and how much is left over

```
ClearAll[buildSplitTree, buildSplitSubtree];
buildSplitTree[counts_, binSizes_, binIdx_ : None] :=
  Block[
   {
    splits,
    binSel
    },
   If[Length[counts] > 1,
    splits = getSplits[counts[[1]], binSizes];
    Association@
     MapThread[
      # -> buildSplitSubtree[# > 0 & /@ #2, #2, counts, binIdx] &,
      splits
      ],
    (* 
    at this point we only have one element in 'counts' left, 
    so there's only one way to distribute these remaining elements
    *)
    {binSizes}
    ]
   ];
buildSplitSubtree[binSel_, binSizes_, counts_, binIdx_ : None] :=
  Block[
   {
    binInds =
     Pick[
      If[binIdx === None, Range[Length@binSizes], binIdx],
      binSel
      ]
    },
   {
    binInds,
    buildSplitTree[counts[[2 ;;]], Pick[binSizes, binSel], binInds]
    }
   ];
```

This will build a tree that tells us where/how to build each element of the desired output, but now we need to reduce this tree to a proper output

```
ClearAll[reduceSplitTree, sowReducedSoln];
reduceSplitTree[cur_, values_, idx_, splitTree_] :=
  Block[{c},
   KeyValueMap[
    Function[
     c = cur;
     MapThread[
      If[#2 > 0, AppendTo[c[[#]], {values[[1]], #2}]] &,
      {idx, #}
      ];
     If[AssociationQ[#2[[2]]],
      reduceSplitTree[c, values[[2 ;;]], #2[[1]], #2[[2]]],
      sowReducedSoln[c, values[[2 ;;]], #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] 
      ]
     ],
    splitTree
    ]
   ];
sowReducedSoln[cur_, values_, idx_, specs_] :=
  Block[{c},
   Do[
    c = cur;
    MapThread[
     If[#2 > 0,
       AppendTo[c[[#]], {values[[1]], #2}]
       ] &,
     {idx, s}
     ];
    Sow[c],
    {s, specs}
    ]
   ];
reduceSplitTree[splitTree_Association, values_] :=
 Reap[
   With[{nbins = Length[Keys[splitTree][[1]]]},
    reduceSplitTree[
     ConstantArray[{}, nbins],
     values,
     Range[nbins],
     splitTree
     ]
    ]
   ][[2, 1]]
```

Finally we can package this workflow up (along with the previous one for testing)

```
treeSplitStuff[ogSet_, bins_] :=
 
 Block[{classes = Counts[ogSet], binSizes, splits},
  binSizes = Length /@ bins;
  splits = buildSplitTree[Values@classes, binSizes];
  reduceSplitTree[splits, Keys@classes]
  ]

naiveSplitStuff[ogSet_, bins_] :=
 Block[
  {testPerms = Permutations[ogSet]},
  Table[
    Map[Sort@p[[#]] &, bins],
    {p, testPerms}
    ] // DeleteDuplicates
  ]
```

This doesn't return the *exact* output I set out for, but this output is workable for me.
And now we see that...for small dimensions all this work is actually *slower* than the naive approach

```
smallOGSet = PadRight[IntegerPartitions[10][[4]], 10]

{8, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

smallBins = TakeList[Range[10], IntegerPartitions[10][[34]]]

{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8}, {9}, {10}}

RepeatedTiming[
 solns = treeSplitStuff[smallOGSet, smallBins];
 ]

{0.0039, Null}

RepeatedTiming[
 naiveSolns = naiveSplitStuff[smallOGSet, smallBins];
 ]

{0.0028, Null}

sortSolns = Sort[Map[Sort] /@ solns];
testSolns = Sort[Map[Tally] /@ naiveSolns];
sortSolns == testSolns

True
```

Where `sortSolns` looks like

```
sortSolns[[;; 5]]

{
 {{{0, 3}}, {{0, 2}}, {{0, 2}}, {{1, 1}}, {{1, 1}}, {{8, 1}}},
 {{{0, 3}}, {{0, 2}}, {{0, 2}}, {{1, 1}}, {{8, 1}}, {{1, 1}}},
 {{{0, 3}}, {{0, 2}}, {{0, 2}}, {{8, 1}}, {{1, 1}}, {{1, 1}}},
 {{{0, 3}}, {{0, 2}}, {{1, 2}}, {{0, 1}}, {{0, 1}}, {{8, 1}}},
 {{{0, 3}}, {{0, 2}}, {{1, 2}}, {{0, 1}}, {{8, 1}}, {{0, 1}}}
 }
```

which is basically a tally of how many of each class are in each bin

This pays off nicely at higher dimensions, though

```
ogSet = PadRight[IntegerPartitions[20][[400]], 15];
bins = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11}, {12, 13, 14}, {15}};

AbsoluteTiming[
 solns = treeSplitStuff[ogSet, bins];
 ]

{0.572987, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[
 naiveSolns = naiveSplitStuff[ogSet, bins];
 ]

{115.691, Null}

sortSolns = Sort[Map[Sort] /@ solns];
testSolns = Sort[Map[Tally] /@ naiveSolns];
sortSolns == testSolns

True
```

But I'm still sure there's a faster/better/more elegant approach out there