# Avoiding duplicates after integer insertions

Tags: performance-tuning

This is related to [Splitting balls over sized bins](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243906/splitting-balls-over-sized-bins/243913#243913) but a simplified subproblem

I've got a list of lists of numbers, e.g.

```
perms = BlockRandom[
   SeedRandom[4];
   RandomInteger[3, {10, 3}]
   ] // DeleteDuplicates

{
 {1, 0, 3},
 {3, 2, 3},
 {1, 2, 1},
 {1, 2, 0},
 {1, 1, 2},
 {2, 0, 2},
 {3, 1, 1},
 {1, 0, 1},
 {1, 0, 0}
 }
```

Now for each of these lists I insert a value at a set of positions, this can be done like

```
insertCurVal[val_, pos_][perms_] :=
  Join @@
   Table[
    Insert[
     perms, 
     val, 
     Transpose[{Range[Length[perms]], ConstantArray[i, Length[perms]]}]
     ],
    {i, pos}
    ];

val = 1;
insertPos = {1, 2};
insertCurVal[1, {1, 2}]@perms

{
 {1, 1, 0, 3},
 {1, 3, 2, 3},
 {1, 1, 2, 1},
 {1, 1, 2, 0},
 {1, 1, 1, 2},
 {1, 2, 0, 2},
 {1, 3, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 0, 1},
 {1, 1, 0, 0},
 {1, 1, 0, 3},
 {3, 1, 2, 3},
 {1, 1, 2, 1},
 {1, 1, 2, 0},
 {1, 1, 1, 2},
 {2, 1, 0, 2},
 {3, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 0, 1},
 {1, 1, 0, 0}
 }
```

This list now has duplicate elements, since for some of the lists an insertion at `1` had the same effect as an insertion at `2`.

Similarly, if we insert at `1` and `3`, we get another set of dupes

```
Counts[insertCurVal[1, {1, 3}]@perms] // Select[GreaterThan[1]]

<|{1, 1, 1, 2} -> 2|>
```

Is there an *efficient* way to avoid these duplicates? That is, is there a way that is better than simply generating the full list and hitting it with `DeleteDuplicates` after the fact? I think I can assume that we'll have tens to hundreds of thousands of these lists but the number of insertion positions will remain under ~50

Comment: maybe `insertCurVal2[val_, pos_][perms_] :=  Module[{assoc = <||>}, 
   Join @@ Table[ AssociateTo[assoc, Thread[Insert[perms, val, Transpose[{Range[Length[perms]], ConstantArray[i, Length[perms]]}]] -> 1]], {i, pos}]];`?

Comment: @kglr isn't that just doing a de-dupe using `AssociateTo` instead of `DeleteDuplicates`? Not sure if that's any faster

Comment: b3m2a1, `ClearAll[insertCurVal3];
insertCurVal3[val_, pos_][perms_] :=  Fold[Join[#,  AssociationThread[
      Insert[perms, val, Transpose[{Range[Length[perms]], ConstantArray[#2, Length[perms]]}]] -> 1]] &, <||>, pos];` is slower for the posted example, but it deletes duplicates as it goes rather than at the end. Something similar with `SparseArray` might be possible as it also ignores repeated entries.

Comment: Honestly, this feels like a chain of x-y problems. Is there some end goal to this and the chain of linked questions?

Comment: @ciao the end goal is basically to take a bunch of lists of integers that can be written as a permutation & a partition of an integer, perform some selection rule math on them where the selection rules can be written, again, as a permutation operating on a partition of _another_ integer + a bunch of factors that come out from taking the direct product of the indices of some D-dimensional array, and reduce all of that to math over the partitions & D-dimensional cube indices. Basically I'm trying to avoid calculating `Permutations[Range[100]]` and work over equivalence classes instead.

Comment: Could `EditDistance[ ]` be useful here? It can, for example, directly tell you if a 5-element list is "reachable" with a single insertion from a 4-element list (their distance = 1). Might be useful in a culling phase.

Comment: @MikeY potentially, although the overarching goal is to avoid having to cull in the first place

Comment: I know, just not seeing a way to do that. Each element in your list of perms has a "distance" from every other element, but it seems to take advantage of that distance, you'd have to compute it for all pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be faster than OP's `insertCurVal` for long lists of `perms`:

The idea: Given a list of insertion positions, `pos = {pos1, pos2, ..., posk}`, if the input list is duplicate-free, the first step of insertions does not introduce any duplicates. If we manage to avoid duplicates up to insertion in $pos_i$, then insertion of `val` in $pos_{i+1}$ creates duplicates iff, for some row `r` of `perms`, the columns `perms[[r, pos_i;;pos_(i+1)]]` are all equal to `val`. So, we remove such rows before we do insertions. The results thus obtained are identical to the ones given by OP's `insertCurVal`.

```
ClearAll[insertCurValB]
insertCurValB[val_, pos_][perms_] := 
  Join[Insert[perms, val, 
        Transpose[{Range[Length[perms]], ConstantArray[First @pos, Length[perms]]}]], 
   Join @@ Table[With[{picked = Pick[Range[Length[perms]], 
         1 - Unitize[Total[Abs[val - perms[[All, i[[1]] ;; (i[[2]] - 1)]]], {2}]], 0]}, 
      Insert[perms[[picked]], val, Thread[{Range @ Length @ picked, i[[2]]}]]], 
   {i, Partition[pos, 2, 1]}]];
```

A faster version using b3m2a1's suggestions in comments:

```
ClearAll[insertCurValC]
insertCurValC[val_, pos_][perms_] := Module[{rng = Range[Length[perms]], 
       lngth = Length@perms}, 
   Join[Insert[perms, val, 
        Transpose[{rng, ConstantArray[First@pos, lngth]}]], 
    Join @@ Table[With[{picked = Pick[rng, 
       1 - Unitize[Total[Abs[val - perms[[All, i[[1]] ;; (i[[2]] - 1)]]], {2}]], 0]},
        Insert[perms[[picked]], val, 
        Transpose[{rng[[;; Length@picked]],
            ConstantArray[i[[2]], Length[picked]]}]]], 
     {i, Partition[pos, 2, 1]}]]];
```

**Examples:**

```
perms = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[4];
    RandomInteger[3, {10, 3}]] // DeleteDuplicates;

(res1 = insertCurVal[1, {1, 2}]@perms // DeleteDuplicates;) // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.000014
> ```

```
(res2 = insertCurValB[1, {1, 2}]@perms;) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.000030
> ```

```
(res2 = insertCurValC[1, {1, 2}]@perms;) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.000037
> ```

```
res1 == res2 == res3
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
perms1000 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[4];
    RandomInteger[3, {1000, 15}]] // DeleteDuplicates;


(res1 = insertCurVal[1, {2, 3, 5, 12}]@perms1000 // 
      DeleteDuplicates;) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0018
> ```

```
(res2 = insertCurValB[1, {2, 3, 5, 12}]@perms1000;) // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0010
> ```

```
(res2 = insertCurValC[1, {2, 3, 5, 12}]@perms1000;) // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.00065
> ```

```
res1 == res2 == res3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Nice! I was working up a solution in this vein since I think it's the optimal one, but kept running into bugs

Comment: One quick performance thing, using `Transpose[{Range@Length@picked, ConstantArray[i[[2]], Length@picked]}]` instead of `Thread[{Range@Length@picked, i[[2]]}]` is significantly faster because it allows us to avoid unpacking. `Thread`, in general, unpacks arrays I believe. I get about a 2x speed up with 10000 input lists. And by only calculating `Range[Length[perms]]` once and subsampling it to get `Range[Length[picked]]` we can get a small but not insignificant boost.

Comment: @b3m2a1, updated with your suggestions.

Comment: I was able to eke a bit more performance out (see my answer) mostly by changing the way I calculated the spec for `Pick`

Comment: A corner case the tests missed: it turns out if you have a case where an insertion will introduce some kind of symmetry this breaks down: ``insertCurValB[1, {1, 2, 3}]@{{1, 0}, {0, 1}} (* {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}} *)`` I think a "wrap-around" case might need to be added

Comment: It seems like this is a problem with two _different_ lists mapping to the same list after two _different_ insertions, which is a nastier case to check for, but if it only ever shows up when inserting both at the very start and very end of the list I think that might be workable

Comment: Another example of breakage by symmetry not requiring a wrap-around: `insertCurValB[1, {2, 4}]@{{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}`

Comment: whoops! looks like we do need to wrap the whole thing with `DeleteDuplicates` after all.

Comment: I think I figured out a way to handle this issue in sub-quadratic runtime, but it is possible that there are other corner cases I've missed

Answer (score 1):

#### Handling Accidental Dupes

With the solution outline by `kglr` we can get into trouble in the special case that we have two lists differ only up to a swap like,

```
dupePerms =
 With[{r = BlockRandom@RandomInteger[{5}, 15]},
  {
   Insert[r, 1, 3],
   Insert[r, 1, 8]
   }
  ]

{
 {0, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2},
 {0, 5, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2}
 }
```

which will cause dupes on when inserting at positions `{3, 9}`

```
insertCurValB[1, {3, 9}]@dupePerms

{
 {0, 5, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2},
 {0, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2},
 {0, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2},
 {0, 5, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2}
 }
```

To handle this case, given `j > i`, when we insert `val` at `j` we can also check for any input lists that have `val` at `j-1` and check for a corresponding list at with `val` at `i`. If we find such a list, we drop that list from our set of insertions.
This is somewhat annoying to program up, but is entirely doable.

```
insertCurValD[val_, pos_][perms_, checkAccidents : True | False : True] :=
  
  Block[{
    p = Range[Length[perms]],
    picked,
    diffs,
    tots,
    subperms,
    subgathers, splitInds,
    potBadPick, potBad1, badVals,
    potBadPickJ, potBadJ, badValsJ,
    badPosJ,
    fullInds,
    balValIndMap
    },
   Join[
    Insert[perms, val, 
     Transpose[{p, ConstantArray[First@pos, Length[perms]]}]],
    Sequence @@
     Table[
      (* remove initial duplicates *)
      
      diffs = 1 - Unitize[(val - perms[[All, i[[1]] ;; (i[[2]] - 1)]])];
      tots = Unitize[Total[diffs, {2}], i[[2]] - i[[1]]];
      picked = Pick[p, tots, 0];
      subperms = perms[[picked]];
      If[checkAccidents,
       (* we first find all positions where val occurs at i[[2]]-1, 
       since these are the possibly duplicated vectors *)
       
       potBadPick = Pick[p, perms[[;; , i[[2]] - 1]], val];
       If[Length[potBadPick] > 0,
        
        (* 
        if we have any of these, then for each prior value of j
        we pull the correspoding vectors with val at position j, 
        but here we are
        able to subsample only the subperms which should make things somewhat \
faster
        *)
        Do[
         potBadPickJ = Pick[p[[;; Length[picked]]], subperms[[;; , j]], val];
         If[Length[potBadPickJ] > 0,
          (* 
          we know we need to check things, 
          so we delete those columns from each set and look at where they overlap
          *)
          fullInds = Range[Length[perms[[1]]]];
          potBad1 = perms[[potBadPick, Delete[fullInds, i[[2]] - 1]]];
          potBadJ = subperms[[potBadPickJ, Delete[fullInds, j]]];
          badVals = Intersection[potBadJ, potBad1];
          balValIndMap = AssociationThread[potBadJ, potBadPickJ ];
          badPosJ = Lookup[balValIndMap, badVals];
          picked = picked[[Complement[p[[;; Length[picked]]], badPosJ]]];
          subperms = perms[[picked]]
          ],
         {j, TakeWhile[pos, # < (i[[2]]) &]}
         ]
        ]
       ];
      Insert[
       subperms,
       val,
       Transpose[{
         p[[;; Length@picked]],
         ConstantArray[i[[2]], Length@picked]
         }]
       ],
      {i, Partition[pos, 2, 1]}
      ]
    ]
   ];
```

and now if we turn this check on we can avoid dupes

```
insertCurValD[1, {3, 9}]@dupePerms

{
 {0, 5, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2},
 {0, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2},
 {0, 5, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2}
 }

insertCurValD[1, {3, 9}][dupePerms, False]

{
 {0, 5, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2},
 {0, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2},
 {0, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2},
 {0, 5, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2}
 }
```

The issue is that this is actually *slower* than just doing a `DeleteDuplicates` after the fact...but I think by being cleverer with the `Intersection` and not wasting effort (we recalculate a lot of stuff) it could become faster.

#### Performance Testing

After trying a number of things, I think making use of kglr's process for removing dupes is about as good as it can get. There are a few places for performance improvements though, particularly w/r/t/ unpacking and calculating the dupe positions. Here's the fastest version I've come up with

```
ClearAll[insertCurValD]
insertCurValD[val_, pos_][perms_] :=
  Block[{
    p = Range[Length[perms]],
    picked,
    diffs,
    tots
    },
   Join[
    Insert[perms, val, 
     Transpose[{p, ConstantArray[First@pos, Length[perms]]}]],
    Sequence @@
     Table[
      diffs = 1 - Unitize[(val - perms[[All, i[[1]] ;; (i[[2]] - 1)]])];
      tots = Unitize[Total[diffs, {2}], i[[2]] - i[[1]]];
      picked = Pick[p, tots, 0];
      Insert[
       perms[[picked]],
       val,
       Transpose[{
         p[[;; Length@picked]],
         ConstantArray[i[[2]], Length@picked]
         }]
       ],
      {i, Partition[pos, 2, 1]}
      ]
    ]
   ];
```

Its performance is not always consistently ~2x faster, but it's never been less than 1.5x that I've seen. This even holds as things become memory bound

```
perms1000 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[4];
    RandomInteger[3, {5000000, 15}]] // DeleteDuplicates;

(res2 = insertCurValB[1, {2, 3, 5, 12}]@perms1000;) // RepeatedTiming // First

12.

(res5 = insertCurValD[1, {2, 3, 5, 12}]@perms1000;) // RepeatedTiming // First

6.80
```

Interestingly, a version using `Compile` was *slower* than the uncompiled version even when making sure there were no `MainEvaluate` statements. My assumption is that this is an effect of being memory constrained over the large lists of partition lists.

Here's a plot & log-log-plot of the performance benefit, just so that we can see it's not a huge difference on a per-list basis

```
perfDat =
  Table[
   With[{p =
      BlockRandom[SeedRandom[4];
        RandomInteger[3, {n, 15}]] // DeleteDuplicates
     },
    {
     {n, AbsoluteTiming[insertCurValB[1, {2, 3, 5, 12}]@p][[1]]},
     {n, AbsoluteTiming[insertCurValC[1, {2, 3, 5, 12}]@p][[1]]},
     {n, AbsoluteTiming[insertCurValD[1, {2, 3, 5, 12}]@p][[1]]}
     }
    ],
   {n, {100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000, 
     10000000}}
   ];

Grid@{{
   ListLinePlot[Transpose@perfDat, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {300, 500}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"B", "C", "D"},
    AspectRatio -> Full
    ],
   ListLinePlot[Transpose@perfDat, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
    ImageSize -> {300, 500},
    PlotLegends -> {"B", "C", "D"},
    AspectRatio -> Full]
   }}
```

[image]